# Sails js SSH DB connection

Tags: ssh, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to connect to a remote DB using SSH programatically from a web application.

I have been trying `ssh2` module and I can connect to the remote server but what I would like to do is to connect directly to the tables in the DB.

I also tried `tunnel-ssh` in the `bootstrap.js` file so I can tunnel to the db but now what I believe is happening is that the db connection is starting before the tunnel is set up and therefore I am getting a `Connection refused`.

Is it possible to achieve this tunneling using some kind of configuration in the `connections.js` file of sails js?
Any other suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally what I did is using a docker-compose with 2 dockers 1) web app and 2) SSH client. My docker-compose file looks something like this:

```
    services:   
      db:
        image: agonza1/sshclient
        volumes:
          - .:/ssh
        command: "ssh -Ng -L 5432:localhost:5432 -i sshkey.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@site.com -p 1234"

      web:
        build: .
        env_file:
          - .env
        ports:
          - "443:443"
        links:
          - db
        depends_on:
          - db
```

where sshclient is just something like this: https://hub.docker.com/r/kroniak/ssh-client/~/dockerfile/